# Issue in defining custom variable & showing in category page in opencart

Tags: opencart2.x

I am facing 1 weird issue in opencart. My version is 2.0.2.0.

My approach to show any custom variable's value in header & footer is....I go to language file & add a variable there then in controller file with $data['...'] & then use that variable in view file.

But my issue here is I can not do this for category page. I wrote a variable in 1) language/english/product/category.php then in 2) catalog/controller/product/category.php & then in 3) template/product/category.tpl but that variable is not coming & instead giving error that.....that variable is not defined so what should I do to achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed any extension that modified category, then check if there is a category.php file there, if so, modify that file instead.

```
\system\modification\catalog\controller\product\category.php
```

Comment: Thanks QDappnet,

Your answer is perfect one & solved my issue :)

Can you please tell why it is so? Yes I have one category named  module then this file should be inside that module's controller....isn't it? :)

But again thanks again for your precious help :)